# What are the minimum and maximum numbers of students possible?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

There are $p$ committees in a class, where $p \geq 5$, each consisting of $q$ members, where $q \geq 6$. No two committees are allowed to have more than $1$ student in common. What are the minimum and maximum numbers of students possible?

Please help me out with this question. I don't know where to start.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the two problems separately:

- Maximum: although two committees can have share a single member, they don't have to, hence we have a maximum of $pq$ people.
- Minimum: Consider this as a graph, where each node is a committee, with an edge between nodes if they share a member. To minimise the number of people we have in the class, we need to maximise the number of edges in this graph, which happens when we have the complete graph $K_p$, with $\frac{p(p-1)}{2}$ edges. This means we have $pq$ people in the committees, but have counted $\frac{p(p-1)}{2}$ people twice, hence there are at least $pq - \frac{p(p-1)}{2}$ people.